# Messages not auto-acknowleging in JBoss 6.1

Tags: java, jboss, hornetq

We recently upgraded from JBoss 4.2 to JBoss 6.1. The new JMS messaging (now using HornetQ)  gets stuck, where there are 15 consumers, but no more than 15 messages are processed. It *looks* like an acknowledge problem, where the messages are not getting acknowledged. They are consumed by a MDB that is written with EJB 2.0, and the acknowledge-mode is Auto-acknowledge (we are currently experimenting with bringing it up to 2.1 to see if that makes a difference). Has anyone experience this? Is there a way to configure the server to Auto-acknowledge by default?

The bean is in a container managed transaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the problem is [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HORNETQ-767?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3achangehistory-tabpanel). Once that exception happens, the queue is basically dead, and will not acknowledge further messages.

Comment: That seems you are doing something wrong with transactions there, or there's something broken on the Transaction manager integration. The TM is not supposed to call xaEnd without xaStart. That API is not really meant to users, so what makes an issue on either the integration with the application server, or there's some invalid TM usage.

Comment: Are you calling acknowledge within a XATransactioned JMSsession? That's an invalid use. We should of course just ignore it on that case.

Comment: @Clebert, yes that is exactly the case, acknowledge is being called in a Transacted JMSession. The JavaDocs on Message.acknowledge state: "Calls to acknowledge are ignored for both transacted sessions and sessions specified to use implicit acknowledgement modes." - So it is supposed to be ignored, not throw an exception. http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/jms/Message.html#acknowledge%28%29

Comment: Ok, I will take a look ands we will fix it,  I would appreciate at least a vote on my answer for the fix. Trying to collect points here :)

Answer (score 2):

You should provide a valid testcase to HornetQ developers (or application server developers) showing that there's a valid usecase you are doing, and it's not an invalid usage.

So far the exception you showed is caused by an invalid XA usage, what doesn't make it a bug on HornetQ so far.

Comment: the bug is clearly outlined in the JIRA issue I linked. I think they got the point, but the use case is easy enough - create a MDB with container managed transactions, and acknowledge the message in the MDB. I got luck that I was able to turn off the acknowledgement, and not in a situation where a library was calling acknowledge.